# module.exports function return undefined isnstead of value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, recursion

I have no idea why exported function `findChilds` return `undefined`

Function look like this:

```
const Folder = module.exports = mongoose.model('folder', FolderSchema);

module.exports = {

    findChilds: (folderId) => {
        Folder.find({
            parent: folderId
        }).then((childs => {
            childs.forEach((child => {
                module.exports.findChilds(child._id)
            }));
            return childs;
        }));
    }

};
```

And calling:

```
const folderModel = require('../models/Folder');

router.get('/remove/:id', (req, res) => {
    let functionResult=folderModel.findChilds(req.params.id);
    console.log(functionResult)
});
```

`functionResult` show only undefined.

Comment: Because your function does not return anything, "think asynchronously"

Answer (score 0):

When using arrow functions, you have 2 ways of returning a value:

Using a single expression without brackets `{}`:

```
module.exports = {
    findChilds: (folderId) => Folder.find({ parent: folderId})
       .then((childs => {
            childs.forEach((child => {
               module.exports.findChilds(child._id)
            }));
            return childs;
        }))
}
```

Using the actual `return` keyword:

```
module.exports = {
    findChilds: (folderId) => {
        return Folder.find({parent: folderId }).then((childs => {
            childs.forEach((child => {
                module.exports.findChilds(child._id)
            }));
            return childs;
        }));
    }
};
```

Keep this in mind when looking at the `forEach` loops inside your `then` method, you'll have problems there as well!

Also english is not my native language, but childs sounds better as children ;)

Comment: There are hundreds of dups of this question.  It's better to point to the best answer of one of those rather than continue to add to the hoard of duplicate answers.